# How to write report for pos printer odoo

Tags: odoo, pos

I want to write report like pos receipt.So My normal qweb report can print in pos printer or how to I write like pos receipt format in odoo.

Comment: How odoo calls the POS receipt report is it loads the template from an xml file. So if you wish to load different report for the POS receipt you inherit & modify that. If you wish to have a new report you create a new screen and load a different template. Try it out

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean.But I want to know is pos printer only print small paper,right? So, do I need to change my template? Can I write like normal qweb report?@clmno